# How do i understand, what is an instance of a class in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am learning OOP in Java, and i have hard time grasping the instance word, and what does it means, and what does it do.

The only thing i do understand is, each object has it own instance of the class, which, when it is changed will be only change in that object, the rest will be unaffected.

Comment: An instance of a class is an object whose type is that class.

Comment: An object *is* an instance of a class. It's not that it *has* one.

Comment: That one is slightly more broad but down the same street it seems

Comment: 'Each object has it own instance of the class' No. Each object *is* an instance of its class.